# CTB’s suction surface

Tags: sentence-construction, phrase-meaning

I am writing a technical paper about a kind of turbine ([Wells turbine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wells_turbine)). Is the use of "CTB’s suction surface" in the following sentence correct grammatically and conceptually?  If not, kindly suggest ways to make it clearer.

> It can be seen that there is a greater vortex on the tip zone of the **CTB’s suction surface** than on that of **the VTB’s suction surface**.

Is the combination of **"the tip zone of the suction surface of the CTB"** correct grammatically?  Which is better in a technical paper?  **"CTB's suction surface"** or **"the suction surface of CTB"**?

...............................

suction surface is a part of the blade of the turbine.

VTB=variable thickness blade
CTB=Constant thickness blade

Comment: English allows "the CTB suction surface", comparable to "the tip zone" (without possessive *'s*). The whole sentence can be much shorter: "*The Vortex on the CTB suction surface tip zone is greater than the VTB's.*"; or: "*The suction surface tip zone vortex is greater for the CTB than the VTB*". (What is point free style)

Comment: Thinking about it, omission of the possessive *'s* is especially important if the blade in the concrete sense doesn't have a suction surface. I guess the suction surface is part of the fluid flow. The abstract sense is implied (what is analytic language).

Answer (score 1):

**Yes, it's correct.**  It's also clearer than "the tip zone of the suction surface of the CTB", because it's more compact.